# Very large HTML5 canvas circle imprecise

Tags: graphics, drawing, html5-canvas

I'm developing an application where users draw euclidean constructions on the HTML5 canvas. As such I can't really limit the size of certain shapes. When exaploring very large circles being drawn on the screen I noticed that very large circles don't have a constant radius.

To be more specific, a circle defined by two points, a center point and one specifing the radius doesn't pass throught the radius point anymore!

[image: Large circle with radius point]

Progressivly larger circles. These are all supposed to pass through point E.

[image: Larger circles]

The error doesn't occure on multiples of 45 degrees = PI/4. Between these multiples the error is biggest (PI/8 for example)

Here is a jsfiddle containing the first example above:

http://jsfiddle.net/D28J2/2/

**My questions: Why does this occure? and Is there some way to (efficently) work around this?**

Comment: on Chrome 16.0.912.63 on MacOS X 10.7.2 the circle in your fiddle _touches_ but does not pass through the required point.

Comment: Interesting, im on Chrome 16.0.912.63 Windows 7 by the way. This issue also occurred on Chrome on Linux. 

On Firefox Windows 7 the same error occurs but is an order of magnitude smaller (only when r = 100 000 is it noticeable).

On IE 9 the error is even smaller (noticeable at r = 1 000 000). 

All these test are preformed with alpha = PI/8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I worked around this issue completely was roll my own implementation of a circle draw approximation with bezier curves. An article detailing the implementation can be found here http://www.tinaja.com/glib/ellipse4.pdf.

```
function magic_circle(ctx, x, y, r){
  m = 0.551784

  ctx.save()
  ctx.translate(x, y)
  ctx.scale(r, r)

  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.moveTo(1, 0)
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(1,  -m,  m, -1,  0, -1)
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(-m, -1, -1, -m, -1,  0)
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(-1,  m, -m,  1,  0,  1)
  ctx.bezierCurveTo( m,  1,  1,  m,  1,  0)
  ctx.closePath()
  ctx.restore()
}
```

With just these four segements I was able to approximate a circle much better then the build in google chrome canvas implementation.

Comment: This is way better than the default arc() method for drawing only circles. I replaced CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.arc with this and it fixed all kinds of weird artifacts and glitching.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a floating point cutoff error.  Possibly because sine and cosine aren't giving perfectly accurate values.  You can get around it (in Chrome at least) by rotating the canvas instead of the arc.

```
ctx.save();          // Save the canvas so we can rotate back.
ctx.translate(x, y); // Translate to the origin point.
ctx.rotate(alpha);   // Rotate the proper angle.

ctx.arc(0, 0, 3, 0, Math.PI*2); // Draw the small circle at the origin.
ctx.fill();

ctx.arc(r, 0, r, 0, Math.PI*2); // Create a big with the origin 1 radius away.
ctx.restore();                  // Restore the canvas to the original orientation
                                // before drawing.  Otherwise the circle looks bad.
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.stroke();                   // Draw!
```

I am a big fan of manipulating the canvas instead of shapes.  It gives you a more logical area to work with.  See http://jsfiddle.net/D28J2/10/

Comment: Wow that's really cool! However that doesn't exactly fix my issue. I need the circle to be 'perfect' everywhere, not just some arbitrary point.

Comment: The circle should perfect everywhere.  The problem was likely not with the radius of the circle but with the the mathematical imprecision of `Math.sin` and `Math.cos` being exaggerated when multiplied by a large constant.  That said, you would have a problem placing any point using the original method, so if you place a second point at x+2*cos(a), y+2*sin(a) it won't line up.  For a truly accurate graph, you need to do all drawing on the rotated canvas.

Comment: The problem is that `Math.cos` and `Math.sin` are implemented by some taylor series in V8. For optimization purposes these taylor series are not very high order hence when drawing very large circles there are errors.

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing this out there but could it be an issue without specifying enough digits of PI? Whenever I do things like that I tend to go slightly overboard and use about 10 digits of PI.

Answer (score 0):

In Google chrome I can repeat the issue but in IE 9 and IE 10 all is fine.

So my guess is that the implementation is wrong in Chrome. It might be a rounding error or they used an interpolation method to avoid sin and cos which isn't very acurate.

Look here as well: [HTML5 canvas arcs not rendering correctly in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603656/html5-canvas-arcs-not-rendering-correctly-in-google-chrome)

The only work around I can imagine is drawing the circle by your own code or using a (jQuery?) plug-in that does this for you.